# Getting started with gnuplot in Ubuntu environment

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I would like to get started with gnuplot in Ubuntu. I have successfully installed the software but I get an error message when I try to plot the sine function. I don't know how to solve this problem and then obtain a plot of my sine function.

```
turbulence@turbulence-LIFEBOOK-AH531:~$ gnuplot> plot sin(x)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to launch gnuplot first (type gnuplot and press enter), and then when you're in give the command (in your case `plot sin(x)`). This is what you should see on the terminal:

```
~$ gnuplot

G N U P L O T
Version 4.6 patchlevel 0    last modified 2012-03-04 
Build System: Linux x86_64

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2012
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'wxt'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
```

Comment: Thank you albus_c for your answer! It works very well!

Comment: Hey! What one should do in order to return to the terminal? Thank you! a

Comment: it's very simple: just type "exit"

Comment: You're welcome. Besides Google, you can see most of gnuplot's commands by typing `help` once you're in gnuplot.

Comment: Great! the world of gnuplot is indeed a better place to be!! a